# R, dplyr and snow: how to parallelize functions which use dplyr

Tags: r, parallel-processing, dplyr, magrittr, snow

Let's suppose that I want to apply, in a parallel fashion, `myfunction` to each row of `myDataFrame`. Suppose that `otherDataFrame` is a dataframe with two columns: `COLUNM1_odf` and `COLUMN2_odf` used for some reasons in `myfunction`.  So I would like to write a code using `parApply` like this:

```
clus <- makeCluster(4)
clusterExport(clus, list("myfunction","%>%"))

myfunction <- function(fst, snd) {
 #otherFunction and aGlobalDataFrame are defined in the global env
 otherFunction(aGlobalDataFrame)

 # some code to create otherDataFrame **INTERNALLY** to this function
 otherDataFrame %>% filter(COLUMN1_odf==fst & COLUMN2_odf==snd)
 return(otherDataFrame)
}
do.call(bind_rows,parApply(clus,myDataFrame,1,function(r) { myfunction(r[1],r[2]) }
```

The problem here is that R doesn't recognize `COLUMN1_odf` and `COLUMN2_odf` even if I insert them in `clusterExport`. How can I solve this problem? Is there a way to "export" all the object that `snow` needs in order to not enumerate each of them?

EDIT 1: I've added a comment (in the code above) in order to specify that the **`otherDataFrame`** is created interally to `myfunction`.

EDIT 2: I've added some pseudo-code in order to generalize `myfunction`: it now uses a global dataframe (`aGlobalDataFrame` and another function `otherFunction`)

Comment: Arguments of your `myFunction` should hold all objects. Try `myFunction <- function(otherDataFrame, fst, snd) {...`.

Comment: in reality otherDataFrame is an object  create in myfunction so I cannot pass to it.

Comment: Rather than using `parApply`, you can use `parLapply`. 
`do.call(bind_rows,parLapply(clus,1:nrow (myDataFrame),function(i, r) { myfunction(r[i,1],r[i,2]) }`. (I haven't tested this. It may still need some fiddling)

Comment: My point still stands - pass all needed objects to the function without referencing to them from outside. Outside is empty once you spawn extra R parallel processes.

Comment: but it is inside the function that I create otherDataFrame: inevitably i cannot pass it to the function. otherDataFrame is an object create inside the function using the parameters passed to the function itself

Comment: @Benjamin I'll check your suggestion asap. but why parLapply should work? What is the difference about parLapply in this particular case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done some experiments, so I solved my problem (with the suggestion of Benjamin and considering the 'edit' that I've added to the question) with:

```
clus <- makeCluster(4)
clusterEvalQ(clus, {library(dplyr); library(magrittr)})
clusterExport(clus, "myfunction", "otherfunction", aGlobalDataFrame)

myfunction <- function(fst, snd) {
 #otherFunction and aGlobalDataFrame are defined in the global env
 otherFunction(aGlobalDataFrame)

 # some code to create otherDataFrame **INTERNALLY** to this function
 otherDataFrame %>% dplyr::filter(COLUMN1_odf==fst & COLUMN2_odf==snd)
 return(otherDataFrame)
}

do.call(bind_rows, parApply(clus, myDataFrame, 1, 
        {function(r) { myfunction(r[1], r[2]) } )
```

In this way I've registered `aGlobalDataFrame`, `myfunction` and `otherfunction`, in short all the function and the data used by the function used to parallelize the job (`myfunction` itself)

Answer (score 1):

Now that I'm not looking at this on my phone, I can see a couple of issues.

First, you are not actually creating `otherDataFrame` in your function.  You are trying to pipe an existing `otherDataFrame` into `filter`, and if `otherDataFrame` doesn't exist in the environment, the function will fail.

Second, unless you have already loaded the `dplyr` package into your cluster environments, you will be calling the wrong `filter` function.

Lastly, when you've called `parApply`, you haven't specified anywhere what `fst` and `snd` are supposed to be.  Give the following a try:

```
clus <- makeCluster(4)
clusterEvalQ(clus, {library(dplyr); library(magrittr)})
clusterExport(clus, "myfunction")

myfunction <- function(otherDataFrame, fst, snd) {
 dplyr::filter(otherDataFrame, COLUMN1_odf==fst & COLUMN2_odf==snd)
}
do.call(bind_rows,parApply(clus,myDataFrame,1,function(r, fst, snd) { myfunction(r[fst],r[snd]), "[fst]", "[snd]") }
```

Comment: i'll try it asap...even though otherDataFrame is created internally to the function (read my last edit) your suggestion is a good way to follow